# SQL Server: Check if entry in both tables if not update missing entry

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I want to run a SP every 10 mins to check if 2 tables, if a value exists in table 1 col1 and not in table 2 col1 then insert a predfined entry into table 2
eg:

```
Table 1:
name age birth
bob 24 england
sally 26 scotland
jim 51 USA

Table 2:
name
bob
jim
```

So the SP would insert Sally into Table2. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: you want to know how to run a SP every 10 mins or insert records to table 2, or both?

Comment: It sounds like you're fixing the wrong problem - why can Table 2 not be just replace with a view called "Table 2" that select name from Table 1?

Comment: Trying to understand how to do the SP, then i can run it it every 10 mins. I cant use a View as some other components use these tables and i cant alter them.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table2(name)
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM table1 tab1
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 tab2 WHERE tab1.name = tab2.name)
```

Got it!